# Tizen Wearable background app

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I am wondering if it is possible to run an tizen wearable app in background. I need to run an app in background. I am using several sensors and I need to save these data continuously.

another thing Can we get the sensor in Samsung Gear S2 data such as Heart Rate directly from an android app directly without any widget on the Gear S2.

I appreciate any help or suggestion.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new on this and I'm starting with Samsung Gear S2.
When I read your post, I thought I read somewhere that Gear S2 would only run web app, yet, I opened the Tizen IDE, used a sample native app, and installed it an ran on Gear S2, so, I would say that you probably can do it. I would just explore the native sample apps for start, you'll have to develop in c/c++ and as you might know, you'll need to instal the Tizen IDE and the Samsung Extension SDK (http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000248)

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't possible in the first Tizen version that supported wearable (2.2) but became possible later (2.3) when native and hybrid apps were added to the wearable profile.

Not sure how running Android apps on Tizen is really implemented, but I'd expect the chances of Anrdoid apps getting access to device information (sensor and other) is fairly unlikely, as those come through Tizen-specific APIs with also Tizen-specific privilege requirements - the mapping would be complex, but who knows, someone may have managed it. You don't need a widget for that though, the same device information API (and more) is available through native apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create wearable background app but only with Tizen 2.3 & above and only in Native app versions not in Web apps.
If you want to build app in web version then u can write your service in native and UI in web app and make the app as hybrid app.

Follow the guide in link below to pack a hybrid app:

[Tizen Hybrid App Packaging guide](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/packaging-hybrid-application?langredirect=1)